# Example of Two Uncountable Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**: An example of two uncountable sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A \oplus B$ is finite (where $\oplus$ represents the symmetric difference).

I tried of thinking of the Ven Diagram because $A \space \text{and} \space B$ cannot share an intersection for the case $A \oplus B$.

I can show two uncountable sets like: $A = \{x \in \mathbb R | x^2 > 0\} $ and $B = \{x\in \mathbb Z | (x=2n) \land (n \in \mathbb R)\}$, but I don't know how make there intersection finite?

Really lost here...

Comment: How is $\oplus$ defined?

Comment: Don't you want the intersection to be infinite if the symmetric difference is to be finite?

Comment: For me I think it was the wording that was throwing me off. So if $A$ is uncountably infinite and $B$ is uncountably infinite, then there intersections must be countable and finite?

Comment: Is $\oplus$ the symmetric difference?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes.

Comment: You should have said so; not standard notation (though perhaps not hard to guess). I've added it explicitly.

Comment: What if $A=B=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @saulspatz, I think I see where you are getting at. If $A = B = \mathbb R$, then there is nothing in their intersection for $A \oplus B$. Making this the empty set?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: @E__: It’s useful to know that $A\oplus B$ is always the set of things that are in exactly one of the sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, So it's basically the intersection of the two sets?

Comment: @E__: Absolutely not: things in $A\cap B$ are **not** in the symmetric difference. It’s $(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$, which is also equal to $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $A \subseteq B$, what is $A \oplus B$?

Comment: Would that be the empty set than?

Comment: Not necessarily! But that's a possible outcome, and it would satisfy the conclusion you're looking for.

Draw this out as Venn diagrams. The answer can be written in terms of $A$ and $B$ using only basic set theory operations (union, intersection, and complement)

Comment: So with this type of problem I am basically seeing what the intersection of these two sets are? Like if their intersection is countable or not?

Comment: It's not their intersection either. In fact, it's everything *except* the intersection! It's the relative complement of $A$ in $B$. That is, it's $B - A = \{x \in B | x \notin A\}$..

Comment: For example if I have two sets $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [2,3]$ then $A \oplus B = \mathbb R$? I feel like I am sort of getting the hang of it...

Comment: @E__ $A\oplus B = (A\cup B) - (A\cap B)$.

Comment: @E__ Err, not quite. Notice that I said that for this, $A \subseteq B$. Your $A$ and $B$ do not satisfy that.

Comment: Specifically, your $A$ and $B$ would just be $A \cup B = [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$.